# Strange homomorphism related to Mackey's theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

On Serge Lang's Algebra p695 about Macky's Theorem, it gives a strange homomorphism. ($E$ a $(R,G)$-modules with $G$ a group and $R$ a commutative ring.)

[image]

But it doesn't seem right to me, $\lambda_2\text{Hom}_G(E_1,E_2)\lambda_1^{-1}$ is not a $\lambda_2G\lambda_1^{-1}$-module homomorphism as on the right:

> Given $\lambda_2\phi\lambda_1^{-1}\in \lambda_2\text{Hom}_G(E_1,E_2)\lambda_1^{-1}$, then for $e_1\in E_1, g\in G$, since $\phi$ is a $G$-module homomorphism,  $\lambda_2\phi\lambda_1^{-1}((\lambda_2 g \lambda_1^{-1})(\lambda_1e_1))=\lambda_2\lambda_1^{-1}\lambda_2 g \phi (e_1)\neq (\lambda_2 g \lambda_1^{-1})\lambda_2\phi(e_1)$, so $\lambda_2 G \lambda_1^{-1}$ doesn't pass through as should of that $\text {Hom}_{\lambda_2G\lambda_1^{-1}}(\lambda_1E_1, \lambda_2E_2)$.

Furthermore,

> when $\lambda_2G\lambda_1^{-1}$ acts on $\lambda_1E_1$ on the first variable of $\text {Hom}_{\lambda_2G\lambda_1^{-1}}(\lambda_1E_1, \lambda_2E_2)$, it becomes $\lambda_2(G E_1)$ which is not even in $\lambda_1E_1$.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\operatorname{Hom}_{\lambda_2G\lambda_1^{-1}}(\lambda_1E_1,\lambda_2E_2)$ appears to be an error.  Indeed, $\lambda_2G\lambda_1^{-1}$ is typically not even a group, so it's unclear what that notation would mean.  What it actually should say is $\operatorname{Hom}_G(\lambda_1 E_1,\lambda_2 E_2)$, where you let $G$ act on $\lambda_i E_i$ by $(g,x)\mapsto \lambda_ig\lambda_i^{-1}x$.